# Android Firebase , show image which is retrieved from firebase in alert dialog

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have been trying to show image which is retrieved from firebase in alert dialog.I have created custom layout for alert dialog. However I count show a image in it.Any image is retrieved with using Glide.Any feedback would be greatly appreciated! You can check my code;

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.aliihsangokalp.casepool, PID: 15517
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
                  at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:27)
                  at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:22)
                  at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:595)
                  at com.example.aliihsangokalp.casepool.CaseSingleActivity$2.onDataChange(CaseSingleActivity.java:112)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeex.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegs.zzbwg(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegy.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

[and also you can check the errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZaPR.jpg)

```
private String mPost_key = null;

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

private TextView mCaseSingleTitle;
private TextView mCaseSingleDesc;
private Button bttn;
private ImageView ımageView;

private ProgressDialog mProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_case_single);



    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cases");

    mPost_key = getIntent().getExtras().getString("case_id");

    mCaseSingleDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleCaseDesc);

    mCaseSingleTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleCaseTitle);
    bttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seeImage);



    final LayoutInflater inf = this.getLayoutInflater();
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);



    bttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final View aaa = inf.inflate(R.layout.photo,null);
             ımageView = aaa.findViewById(R.id.singleCaseImage);

            final AlertDialog.Builder ImageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CaseSingleActivity.this);


            ImageDialog.setTitle("Here is the photo : ");
            ImageDialog.setView(aaa);



            ImageDialog.setNegativeButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                }
            });
            ImageDialog.show();


           }});

        mDatabase.child(mPost_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                String post_title = (String) dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue();
                String post_desc = (String) dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue();
                String post_image = (String) dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue();
                String post_uid = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();

                mCaseSingleTitle.setText(post_title);
                mCaseSingleDesc.setText(post_desc);

                Glide.with(CaseSingleActivity.this).load(post_image).apply(new RequestOptions().fitCenter().override(1000,1000).dontAnimate().dontTransform()).into(ımageView) ;

                mProgress.dismiss();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        mProgress.dismiss();
        }
          });
          }
         }
```

Comment: Looks like your post_image value is null, check your json

Comment: @diegoveloper nope. It is not null. When I set it directly to Imageview without Alert dialog, I can get it easily.

Comment: Ok oh, so looks like your imageview is null when you call glide, put a log printing your imageview before glide

Comment: Edit your question to include the error message as text please. Screenshots of textual content are not nearly as useful as having the actual text itself.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have edited it. If you need more details I can share.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Have you checked it ?

Comment: As your stack trace says, you're passing `null` into `into()`. Given the code you shared, that seems to be in `into(ımageView)`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have no problem when I set image  to Imageview Glide.with(CaseSingleActivity.this).load(post_image).apply(new RequestOptions().fitCenter().override(1000,1000).dontAnimate().dontTransform()).into(ımageView) ;  and. ımageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.case_image); and everything is fine.However i couldn't carry it to popup window. when I run popup, android studio says it s null.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the path of your Database is null, Please store the `Intent`'s `putExtra()` key in a constant `public static final` variable so you don't mistakenly type a new key when retrieving it.

> Check your `Intent` extra

```
public static final String key = "case_id";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ToYourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key, "urlOfImage.com/fsfd/asd.jpg");
startActivity(intent);

//retrieving from another class
mPost_key = getIntent().getExtras().getString(PeviousClass.key);
```

Comment: still null. and I declare it as static in previous activity. here my intent. I have to get all datas by different users. As I mentioned, I have no problem without alert dialog. I can retrieve all in next activity to set them directly to the single layout      Intent singleCaseInten = new Intent(CaseListActivity.this,CaseSingleActivity.class);
                    singleCaseInten.putExtra(key,post_key);
                    startActivity(singleCaseInten);